# Вернуть значение функции js мне

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, html5

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста новичку, как вернуть значение out'a ? фактически есть имена twich каналов- данная функция хотелось бы чтобы возвращала массив json объектов полученных по данных именам channels

```js
function getMasApi(mas) {
  var out = [];
  mas.forEach(function(el, i) {
    $.getJSON(api + el, function(json) {
      //console.log(json);
      out.push(json);
      //console.log(out);
    });
  });
  console.log(out);
  return out;
};

var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

let api = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/";

getMasApi(channels);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getChannelsArray = () => {
    const channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    let channelArray = [];

      channels.forEach((channel) => {
          $.getJSON(`https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/${channel}`, (data) => {
            channelArray.push(data);
            
            // Для наглядности вызову функцию, которая отобразит результаты (одно свойство объекта в качестве примера) на странице
            viewResult(data.name);
          })
      });

      return channelArray;
    }

    const out = getChannelsArray(); //нужный вам массив

    //Функция отображения данных на странице (для наглядности)
    function viewResult(data) {
      $('.text').append(`<li>${data}</li>`); 
    }
```

```html
<ul class="text"></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: если до return channelArray попытаться вывести в консоль : console.log(channelArray) он выведет '[]'. в этом то и вопрос - целевой массив не заполняется

Comment: @Dima это асинхронный код. Пока делается ваш JSON запрос код идет ниже. И строчка с console.log() выполняется быстрее, чем приходит ответ с сервера и заполняется Ваш массив. Весь ваш код нужно выполнять ПОСЛЕ того, как вы получили ответ от сервера (данные).

Comment: да, я ведь и хотел получить ответ как сделать так чтобы последовательно все выполнялось, разобрался вот в промисах немного - реализовал, скоро выложу, интересно ваше мнение кстати